can I capture perfetto trace over usb or network?
Can I capture perfetto trace over usb or network?
I want to keep capturing perfetto trace and send over usb or network to PC to save while running testcase on device. so keep writting disk file won't affect long time test.
how can I do that?

what OS? android?

here is instruction how to capture perfetto trace thru adb:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/perfetto/+/refs/heads/pie-gsi/docs/running.md

however, it doesn't tell me how to save perfetto trace to pc directly.
do you know how to do that?
the background why I want to do that:
I want to mark performance test scene by trace in long time performance test,   then use trace_processor extract all performance test scene at once , and automatically  caclcaute performance kpi from trace.
